# Joomla Pagination

Tags: php, joomla, pagination

I have successfully implemented the pagination box in a component front end listing template. however, when i try to set the limit of listing items, it won't work, i wonder what is missed out.

**in the model**

```
  var $_total = null;

  /**
   * Pagination object
   * @var object
   */
  var $_pagination = null;


  function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();

    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();

    // Get pagination request variables
    $limit = $mainframe->getUserStateFromRequest('global.list.limit', 'limit', $mainframe->getCfg('list_limit'), 'int');
    $limitstart = JRequest::getVar('limitstart', 0, '', 'int');

    // In case limit has been changed, adjust it
    $limitstart = ($limit != 0 ? (floor($limitstart / $limit) * $limit) : 0);

    $this->setState('limit', $limit);
    $this->setState('limitstart', $limitstart);
  }


     function _buildQuery(){
         $query = ' SELECT * '
                 . ' FROM #__event '
                 .'Where published = 1'
            ;

         return $query;
    }

      function getData() {
    // if data hasn't already been obtained, load it
            if (empty($this->_data)) {
            $query = $this->_buildQuery();
            $this->_data = $this->_getList($query, $this->getState('limitstart'), $this->getState('limit'));    
            }
            return $this->_data;
      }


    function getTotal(){
    // Load the content if it doesn't already exist
        if (empty($this->_total)) {
        $query = $this->_buildQuery();
        $this->_total = $this->_getListCount($query);       
        }
        return $this->_total;
     }

    function getPagination(){
     // Load the content if it doesn't already exist
        if (empty($this->_pagination)) {
        jimport('joomla.html.pagination');
        $this->_pagination = new JPagination($this->getTotal(), $this->getState('limitstart'), $this->getState('limit') );
        }
        return $this->_pagination;
    }
```

**in the views/view.html.php (full version of this document)**

```
 class EventViewListing extends JViewLegacy
{ 
// Overwriting JView display method
function display($tpl = null) 
{

            $model= & JModelLegacy::getInstance('Event','EventModel');
            $pagination = $model->getPagination();
            $this->assignRef('pagination',   $pagination);



  $JDoc =& JFactory::getDocument();
  $db = JFactory::getDBO();

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM #__event WHERE published = 1 ORDER BY id DESC";
  $db->setQuery($sql);
  $rows = $db->loadObjectList();


  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM #__user_usergroup_map WHERE group_id = 5 or group_id = 8";
  $db->setQuery($sql2);
  $rows2 = $db->loadObjectList();


   $this->assignRef('rows',$rows);
   $this->assignRef('rows2',$rows2);


 //  $JDoc->setTitle('  ');

    // Display the view
    parent::display($tpl);
}
}
```

**in the default.php**

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_event'); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm">


<?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="GO!"  /> 
</form>
```

hope someone could help
thank you!

Comment: Can you try to echo $this->getState('limitstart'); die(); in your getData() method? I wonder if it gets the correct value.

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: Joomla 3.2, i am building my own component

Comment: this is the url, index.php?option=com_event&limitstart=0, i can select the limit number and click on 'go' to update the limit, but the listing item amount won't change, i guest the query may be wrong.

Comment: So is the pagination showing up wrong or are the wrong number of items displayed on the page or can you not navigate to the second page?

Comment: The pagination always showing up all the listing items in the database, instead of showing only stated number of items of choosing limitstart in one page.

Comment: `limitstart` tells you which page that you are on. So if you have 100 items, and your `limit` is 20, you would see the first 20 items and pagination would show 5 page links. `limitstart` would be 20 to go to page show (which would still show 20 items). I don't see anything wrong in your code, but I'm not sure if you are setting limitstart to something accurately to move through the pages...

Comment: hi, i updated the full version of the view.html.php, in which i also select the full list from database, will this be redundant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limits need to also be used in the queries to limit the number of records that are displayed to the page that you are on. Typically this can be done in the setQuery function, which allows a second and third parameter to set the limit size and start position.

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM #__event WHERE published = 1 ORDER BY id DESC";
  $db->setQuery($sql, $model->getState('limitstart'), $model->getState('limit'));
  $rows = $db->loadObjectList();


  // I'm not sure what this query is for, but since it probably isn't supposed to be limited to a set number of items, don't update it's setQuery call.
  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM #__user_usergroup_map WHERE group_id = 5 or group_id = 8";
  $db->setQuery($sql2);
  $rows2 = $db->loadObjectList();
```

I think that fixes the problem that you are having.

---

That being said, you have a host of minor issues that are making this a lot harder for you or just using outdated practices:

```
 $limitstart = JRequest::getVar('limitstart', 0, '', 'int');
```

Using JRequest::getVar() is deprecated and likely to be removed in future versions of Joomla. Instead use this:

```
 $limitstart = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('limitstart', 0, 'INT');
```

Note that the parameters have changed slightly. This uses a different class to parse input to the application.

```
$this->assignRef('rows',$rows);
```

The above is unnecessary anymore (was only needed back in PHP4 from what I understand). Instead just do `$this->rows = $rows;`

Finally, the big overall issue is that you aren't really using Joomla's help.

Your model should just be extending from the class `JModelList` since you are trying to create a list of events. If you extend from that class and name your functions properly, Joomla will do most of the work:

1. Rename `_buildQuery` to `getListQuery`.
2. Pretty much delete every other function in your model, since Joomla has all of them in JModelList doing basically the same things.
3. Update your view to this:

   ```
   class EventViewListing extends JViewLegacy
   { 
   // Overwriting JView display method
   function display($tpl = null) 
   {

     $JDoc = JFactory::getDocument();
     $db = JFactory::getDBO();

     $this->pagination = $this->get('Pagination');
     $this->rows = $this->get('Items');

     $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM #__user_usergroup_map WHERE group_id = 5 or group_id = 8";
     $db->setQuery($sql2);
     $this->rows2 = $db->loadObjectList();

     //  $JDoc->setTitle('  '); 

        // Display the view
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
    }
   ```

`$this->get()` in the JViewLegacy class will call the model (with the same name as the view) and run the method of that model that starts with `get` followed by whatever word is in the function, so `$this->get('Pagination')` calls the models `getPagination` function.

And again, all of the functions that you are adding in the model exist already in `libraries/legacy/model/list.php`, so just use them!

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very useful information for me. Thank you!